# understanding parameters passed to -p flag in Docker

Tags: docker

I was just going throught the docker doc's **[HERE](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/)** and saw the below command:

```
$ docker run -d -P training/webapp python app.py
```

The below

```
training/webapp
```

Is basically the image , what is `python` and `app.py` ?? what are they really doing ? I am having a hard time trying to understand what these two commands or parameters are doing , can anybody explain ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the reference for [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/)? What in particular is unclear?  All those parameters you're asking about have explicit documentation there.

Comment: @larsks , yess i am reading the documentation sequentially , i had seen that .. just could't find it , Thanks though. :)

Comment: So if you can update your question to indicate which part of that document isn't clear  -- referring to specific text -- we can provide you with a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the first link in the Documentation you posted:

> In the [Using Docker section](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/usingdocker/), you created a container that ran a Python Flask application:
>
> `$ docker run -d -P training/webapp python app.py`

Then going to the "User Docker section":

> For our web application we’re going to run a Python Flask application. Let’s start with a docker run command.
>
> `$ docker run -d -P training/webapp python app.py`
>
> Let’s review what our command did. We’ve specified two flags: -d and -P. We’ve already seen the -d flag which tells Docker to run the container in the background. The -P flag is new and tells Docker to map any required network ports inside our container to our host. This lets us view our web application.
>
> We’ve specified an image: training/webapp. This image is a pre-built image we’ve created that contains a simple Python Flask web application.
>
> Lastly, we’ve specified a command for our container to run: python app.py. This launches our web application.